# AOL styling problems - two fixed sidebar one fluid content layout

Tags: javascript, css, aol

I have adapted the holy grail three column layout into my site and it works great, except in AOL.  I can easily use JavaScript to detect AOL and write new CSS styles after the rest have been evaluated, using document.write(' ');, but even with that freedom I cannot for the life of my style the page right.  I was hoping someone could help.  Here is the trial page with all evaluated imports etc.:

[link text](http://www.sinaesthesia.co.uk/threecol2.php5)

Any help at all would be great...I need the nav buttons to sit on the breadcrumb bar, the container div to sit flush under that, the left column to be blue to the footer, the center white, the right sidebar to be blue to the footer and...that's it.  Doesn't sound hard, right?

My infinite gratitude to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now use PHP to add inline style rules setting the center div to a fixed with and adjusting margins etc.